# Changing from .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1 causes app not to run

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a .NET web application that was originally running on .NET 3.5 but upgraded it to .NET 4.5.1. When I attempt to run the application, I get the following error:

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file 
required to service this request. Please review the specific error details 
below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that 
attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


Line 63:        debugging ASP.NET files.
Line 64:        -->
Line 65:        <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
Line 66:        <!--  CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES
Line 67:        Set customErrors mode="On" or "RemoteOnly" to enable custom error messages, "Off" to disable. 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8745; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8745
```

As you can see by the last line, this application is still using .NET Framework verison 2.0.50727.8745.

I asked my colleague to open the solution after getting it from source control and run it and it uses .NET 4.0.* and he doesn't see this error. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my machine. I have looked in the applicationhost.config and I don't even see my application listed, much less anything regarding which .NET version it's using. Why would it work on his machine and not mine? I have a bug fix I need to implement and if I can't run the application that isn't going to happen.

Comment: Are you debugging the application in visual studio? If so, is it set to IISExpress publishing? Project Properties -> Web -> Servers

Comment: can you please elaborate how you "Upgraded to .net 4.5.1" ?

Comment: It wasn't me but another developer that changed the .NET Framework version in the project properties. There was a component he wanted to use that required using a version higher than 3.5. We're supposed to change all our applications to use .NET 4.7 within the next couple of months.

Answer (score 2):

Change your app pool to use v4.0 runtime. It is entirely possible that the machine it is failing on does not even have v4.0 runtime installed.

Comment: I'm using IIS Express on my development machine which has Visual Studio 2017 Professional with all the updates installed. I know I have .NET 4.0 installed because all my other applications use it. I have several apps using 4.7 and I don't have this problem.

Comment: Your answer is correct if you are using IIS but I am not. I ended up deleting the solution folder and then pulling the solution from source control and now everything works. There must have been something not in source control that was causing this issue. I wish I knew what it was.

Comment: @DesertFoxAZ Agreed. In my experience, errors or issues which resolve themselves without external help have a habit of coming back at the most inopportune time. Keep an eye out for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of IIS Express config `applicationhost.config` which is located in `.vs` directory. It contains application pool assignment to your project:

```
<system.applicationHost>

    <applicationPools>
        <add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="Clr4ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="Clr2IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="Clr2ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
        <add name="UnmanagedClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Classic" autoStart="true" />
        <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeLoader="v4.0">
            <processModel />
        </applicationPoolDefaults>
    </applicationPools>

    <sites>
        <site name="YourWebSite" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr2IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\YourWebSite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:46397:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
    </sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

You can change the pool your project uses... in theory. I tried but it didn't help. The working solution is to remove `.vs` directory and open your solution again. `.vs` directory will be created again with correct config.